# How to fix PLS-00103 error in Zip Code function?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I've created a function to determine the existence of a zip code in a table. I have a table called "ZIPCODE" and a column called "ZIP". For this function, I want it to return a boolean value of true or false whether the zip code exists or not. However, I get this error:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "13501" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with

So the issue occurs after I input a zip.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip_existence 
RETURN number IS

bool number (2) := 0;

BEGIN
    &zip_input;

     FOR record_current_zip IN current_zip LOOP
        IF record_current_zip = zip_input THEN
            bool := 0;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode in use!');
        IF record_current_zip != zip_input  THEN
            bool := 1;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode not in use');
                END IF;
            END IF;
        RETURN boolean; 
    END loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

`&zip_input` is a client substitution variable, which is evaluated when the function is compiled - which is unlikely to be what you want. Where you are using it doesn't make sense anyway though, and the later *slightly* more logical references don't have the `&` prefix. So at the moment you appear to be doing:

```
define zip_input = 13501;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip_existence 
RETURN number IS

bool number (2) := 0;

BEGIN
    &zip_input;

     FOR record_current_zip IN current_zip LOOP
....
END; 
/
```

which does indeed get `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "13501"...` because that is expanded to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip_existence 
RETURN number IS

bool number (2) := 0;

BEGIN
    13501;

     FOR record_current_zip IN current_zip LOOP
...
```

and that `13501` doesn't belong there.

You should be passing the value you want to check as a formal argument to the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip_existence (zip_input zipcode.zip%TYPE)
RETURN number IS
  bool number (1) := 0;
BEGIN
...
```

But there are further issues

- you're using a `current_zip` cursor that you haven't defined;
- within that loop you're comparing

  ```
  IF record_current_zip = zip_input THEN
  ```

  which is referring to the record instead of the field within the record, so it should be

  ```
  IF record_current_zip.zip = zip_input THEN
  ```
- you then have a second `IF` *within* the first one, which has the same field issue but more importantly which can never evaluate to true -  you really want that to be an `ELSE` I think;
- also within the loop you're going to set `bool` to zero when you find a match, but it starts as zero anyway, and even if you fix the `IF` problem you're going to return based on the first record to get from the cursor. It looks like you want to loop over all possible ZIP codes - but you don't, and if you did (returning later) then you'd keep overwriting that `bool` result;
- so you could start with `bool` set to the 'not found' state, and *only* change that if you do find a match;
- your `return` has `boolean` (which is a PL/SQL type) instead of `bool` (your variable).

So one way to do this might be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip_existence (zip_input zipcode.zip%TYPE)
RETURN number IS
  bool number (1) := 1; -- start with not-found state
  cursor current_zip is
    select * from zipcode;
BEGIN
  FOR record_current_zip IN current_zip LOOP
    IF record_current_zip.zip = zip_input THEN
      bool := 0;
    END IF;
  END loop;

  -- debugging only - client may not see this
  IF bool = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode in use!');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode not in use');
  END IF;

  RETURN bool; 
END; 
/
```

You don't really want to loop over all values looking for a match anyway - a single select filtering on the passed-in value would be much more efficient, possibly something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip_existence (zip_input zipcode.zip%TYPE)
RETURN number IS
  bool number (1);
BEGIN
  select case when count(*) > 0 then 0 else 1 end
  into bool
  from zipcode
  where zip = zip_input;

  -- debugging only - client may not see this
  IF bool = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode in use!');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode not in use');
  END IF;

  RETURN bool; 
END; 
/
```

If `ZIP` isn't unique then you might benefit from adding a `where rownum <= 1` filter to the query.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick response and offering 2 solutions. And thanks for point out the other issues I didn't find originally. I definitely like how solution 2 is much more efficient.

Comment: I have one more question, if I can't use substitution varibles, how will I ask the user for input?

Comment: @moneenja - you can still use client functionality like substitution variables for the call if you want, e.g. `select zip_existence(&enter_zip) from dual;`